# Why can file expansion work for filenames with a newline character?

Tags: bash

```
$ rm Think\ Python:\ How\ to\ Think\ Like\ a\ Computer
\ Scientist\ 2014.pdf 
rm: cannot remove ‘Think Python: How to Think Like a Computer’: No such file or directory
$  Scientist 2014.pdf: command not found
$ rm Think*
$
```

In the first `rm`, I use autocompletion in bash to specify a file with a newline character in its filename, and it doesn't work because of the newline character.

In the second `rm`, I use file expansion to avoid explicitly to specify the new line character. Why can file expansion avoid the problem? Doesn't file expansion expand to the full filename which contains the new line character too?

Comment: I think it's more a question of why autocompletion fails to add a backslash before the newline, and less a question about file expansion.

Comment: By the way autocompletion in cygwin's bash quotes the filename including the newline character.

Comment: Interesting the tidbit about cygwin.

Comment: For me it was more difficult to create the file\n than understanding why this happens...I used to be a assembly developer.

Answer (score 1):

In the case of rm of the file ending in \n, `rm file*`, the regexp file expansion "eats" the new line as part of the rm argument, so the shell does not see it and does not parse it as a command.

As seen in a strace:

```
$strace rm teste.txt* 
execve("/bin/rm", ["rm", "teste.txt\n"],
```

As for autocompletion obeys to a set of pre-defined rules, and it does not really expect to have a '\n' there.